# Signal Correlation time computation for Time delay estimation

Tags: autocorrelation, localization

I need to compute the Signal Correlation Time of an audio signal to check wether time-delay estimations are anomalous. In [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/486067?casa_token=b0qnalpNKvsAAAAA:odGm6zByjJiwF-ogRRGs2-R5K5a58lgo8TMif3iX-y4jA-YXKqikgpjHv5BSsC92q8YyU3EZvUs) The Signal correlation time is defined as the width of the main lobe of the signal autocorrelation function (taken between the -3 dB points).

Therefore after computing and normalizing (between 0 and 1) the autocorrelation function I should check the distance in lags between the points where the function drops to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Am I correct? Is the following Python implementation correct? Many thanks for your time!

```py
def compute_correlation_time(signal):
  # Compute the autocorrelation function
  # signal is a 1D numpy array with N samples
  autocorr = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(abs(np.fft.fft(signal))**2))

  # Normalize the autocorrelation function
  normalized_autocorr = autocorr / np.max(autocorr)

  # Find the -3 dB points
  half_max = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
  indices = np.where(normalized_autocorr >= half_max)[0]
  left_3db, right_3db = indices[0], indices[-1]

  # Compute the correlation time as the width between the -3 dB points
  correlation_time_samples = right_3db - left_3db
  print(str(correlation_time_samples))
  return correlation_time_samples
```

Comment: What type of testing have you done yourself already? Did you try some simple signals with known answers? I suggest doing that first and then asking more specific question if you run into problems.

Comment: 1. I would double check if the threshold should be $1/\sqrt 2$ or $1/2$ that you are interested.
2. Maybe you are interested only on the width of contiguous samples greater than the threshold.